# Scala Controller that calls the Dao methods to get the objects and convert to json

Tags: scala, playframework

anyone has good examples on the `Scala Controller` that calls the `Dao methods` to get the objects, and convert to json for my reference? I got stuck on the following `Controller` `getProject(id)`. Please advise.

Thanks

```
@Singleton
abstract class ProjectController @Inject()(projectDao: ProjectDao) extends BaseController() 
{
      def index(): Action[AnyContent] = Action {
        Ok(com.workday.appsec.midi.views.html.index("Your application is ready."))
      }

      def getProject(id: Long): Action[AnyContent] = Action { implicit request =>
        val proj: Future[Option[Project]] = projectDao.getProjectById($id)

        //TODO: GET STUCK HERE!!
        //need to convert to json object and return to the response
        Json.toJson(proj)   
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample project that I did. You might find this helpful!

https://github.com/joesan/plant-simulator/blob/master/app/com/inland24/plantsim/controllers/PowerPlantController.scala

The idea is that, you use play json library to serialize de-serialize your case classes to and from json.

Answer (score 0):

You just pass object to Ok 
proj.flatMap {
 case Some(prj)=>Future.successful(Ok(prj))
 case None:
}

Comment: what does this do?